# Getting the index of an element in a deque given a pointer to that element?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, iterator, deque

Is there any way to get the index of an element from a pointer to the element? To be specific, what I need is the index (or iterator) to the element preceding or following the one I point. I know that when using vectors you can easily do the arithmetics but in a deque it is not so easy.

I have to use deque. Vectors are not an option.

Comment: No, deques don't save the indices along with the values, otherwise insertion and removal would be `O(n)`. So finding the index is an `O(k)` operation if you only have the pointer where `k` is the maximum possible index of the item (that is, `k == n` if the item could be anywhere).

Comment: so the only way to get that index is to search the element through the whole deque?

Comment: Exactly, if you have only the pointer, this is the only way. Maybe you can access the data structure in a different way?

Comment: the problem is that i want to save pointers to the elements of deque in other array so that i could easily access and modify them. In the meantime I push and pop elements from the deque and that is why I'm not using vectors. But maybe I'm wrong and it could be done easier so please tell me.

Comment: Well, you could just save pointers to your values in the deque. Then you could store the same pointers somewhere else as well and use them to access the values.

Comment: @Nikklas proposes the correct solution.  You shouldn't have redundant containers containing the same items or references to the same item.  You may consider using shared pointers to handle the book-keeping for the object references without having to juggle dynamic memory management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is no. But why not use iterators rather than pointers throughout?

Comment: In the meantime I push and pop elements from the deque. That is why.

Comment: But why use pointers for that rather than iterators? ... Wait. Are you (1) storing *objects* in the deque and keeping *pointers to* those objects in the deque, or (2) storing *pointers* in the deque and keeping *those same pointers*? If the former, then I'd have thought you'd do better to use iterators. If the latter, then what you're asking for is the ability to search a deque for a particular item, and that's always going to be slow.